# How would I remove apostrophe from the start and end of words, but not from within the word?

Tags: java, regex

While reading and learning about regex, I have been trying to figure out why I go wrong in the current usage of my regex?

The string I have is

```
String sentence = "I would've rather stayed at home, than go to the Murphys' home, on the 'golden' weekend";
```

The current replaceAll argument I use is:

```
String[] tokens = sentence.replaceAll("[^\\sA-Za-z']+", "").split("\\s+");
```

This gives me an array of tokens that looks like

```
tokens = {"I", "__would've__", "rather", "stayed", "at", "home", "than", "go", "to", "the", "__Murphys'__", "home", "on", "the", "__'golden'__", "weekend"};
```

But I would like to remove the apostrophe from **Murphys'** to **Murphys** and **'golden'** to **golden** while **would've** stays as **would've**.

Giving me an array that looks like

```
correctTokens = {"I", "__would've__", "rather", "stayed", "at", "home", "than", "go", "to", "the", "__Murphys__", "home", "on", "the", "__golden__", "weekend"};
```

Your help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I think you missed one `the` before `Murphys` in the expected output. What about a matching approach? See https://ideone.com/kY71Py

Comment: Duly Noted. Also, any advice for how I could tackle my predicament?

Comment: Use `"\\p{L}+(?:'\\p{L}+)?"` to collect matches. Or, `"(?U)\\b\\p{L}+(?:'\\p{L}+)?\\b"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `replaceAll("[^\\h\\v\\p{L}']+|(?<=\\P{L}|^)'|'(?=\\P{L}|$)", "")`

Explanation:

- `[^\h\v\p{L}']+` One or more characters that are not:

  - Unicode (horizontal or vertical) whitespace
  - Unicode letter
  - Apostrophe `'`
- `|` or
- `(?<=\P{L}|^)'` A apostrophe preceded by a non-letter or beginning of input
- `|` or
- `'(?=\P{L}|$)` A apostrophe followed by a non-letter or end of input

See [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/jGYngJ/1) for demo.

Comment: `(?<=\P{L}|^)` is less efficient and portable than `(?<!\p{L})`. Also cf. `(?=\P{L}|$)` vs. `(?!\p{L})`. `[\h\v]` = `(?U)\s`.

Answer (score 0):

try regex: `\\s'|'\\s` and replace with space

```
String sentence = "I would've rather stayed at home, than go to the Murphys' home, on the 'golden' weekend";

String[] tokens = sentence.replaceAll("\\s'|'\\s", " ").split("\s+");
```

**output**

```
[I, would've, rather, stayed, at, home,, than, go, to, the, Murphys, home,, on, the, golden, weekend]
```